# Layout handle for all account related pages

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-1, customer-account

I have bookmarked this website to peek at the available layout handles:
http://itpscan.info/blog/magento/layout_handles.php

I saw a few handles regarding the account page. I was wondering, **is there also a handle that I can use for all account pages?**

Account pages being:

- account overview
- Personal settings
- Adresses
- My trips
- My trip reviews

(Names can be a bit different, since I am using a Dutch installation, made for a boat that sells voyages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Can use below kind of handler for that

`<customer_logged_in>`

`<customer_logged_out>`

`<customer_account>` you can use this one on all dashbord pages .

If you want to see all handler for your particular page then use this code to see all handler for your current page.

```
var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

you can use above code in any phtml file and php files , this code print all possible handler for that particular page hope this will help you

Comment: Wow, that code to check the handlers on my current page is very handy! Thanks alot!

Comment: You are always welcome Bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `<customer_account>` handle is the handle that can be used for every account page.

Comment: Well look at that! I thought that handle was used for the account overview page

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen nope the account overview is `<customer_account_index>`